# How to Broadcast a file(.mp3) over local wifi? and synchronize the play when both devices have the file?

Tags: iphone, wifi, gamekit, gksession, gkpeerpickercontroller

I know my question is very big. but if some one cod suggest me what direction should i go to.
I know we can implement this by gameKit(GKsession/GKPeerPickerController) but i cant really understand the working of these two properly also, How can i synchronies they play after receiving data.

Thank alot guys any help is appreciated